# Difficulty to satisfy test cases of first euler project

Tags: java, testing

I recently got started with the Euler project. This is my first project which is not getting implemented for test cases 2,3,4. Please have look at my code and tell me what test cases have been missed.

The problem can be found on this webpage: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler001/problem

My code :

```
import java.io.*;
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
    int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    int arr[] = new int[testCases];
    if(testCases <= 1 || testCases >= 100000)
    {System.out.print("exit 1");
        System.exit(0);}
    for(int i = 0; i < testCases; i++)
    {

        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());  
        if(arr[i] <= 1 || i >= 1000000000 )
        {System.out.print("exit 2"); 
            System.exit(0);}        }
    for(int i = 0; i < testCases; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(FactorSum( arr[i] ) );   
    }
}

public static int FactorSum(int input)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < input ; i++)
    {
        if(i%5 == 0 || i%3 == 0)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```

Please help !

Comment: Note condition (from reference) `1<= T <= 100000` ; your code excludes T=1 and T=100000.  Similarly `1 <= N <= 10^9` ; your code excludes N=1 and N=10^9.

Comment: Hey, @Andy I followed your advice. Now I am not longer getting the error for test case 4 but the program is still not getting satisfied for test case 2 and 3.Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Evidently the site assesses *both* correctness and algorithm efficiency (through the use of a timeout mechanism.)

The host expects O(T) - in your solution it is O(T*N) due to your factorization loop and the extra loop in main - consider the difference in complexity when N=10^9.  (How they assess this appears to be as simple as a fixed time limit - see [environment](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment).)

Also be sure to consider the "edge cases" for T (looks like you have that covered) and N (specifically N=10^9) as your code fails in this edge case (for reasons of 'incorrect' and 'timeout').  The 'incorrect' fail is a result of not considering the range of language types used.

I'd strongly recommend reading the discussion session on each problem as this is discussed thoroughly.

Also, one more change for correctness beyond the one in the comment:

Change

```
if(arr[i] <= 1 || i >= 1000000000 )
```

to

```
if(arr[i] < 1 || arr[i] > 1000000000 )
```

Note you used `i` when you meant `arr[i]` (and this also includes the inclusive change).

You will need to solve the factorization-summation **without a loop** on N.  That is the essence of what they are testing aside from correct output.

Once again, emphasis on *read the discussion section of site for each problem*.
Good luck.